# AZURE SQL DB Vulnerability Assessment mark High risk after Database fire wall setup

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

[image]

I have setup Azure ATP on Azure sql server and removed all the fire wall settings from the server. However after that when I ran the vulnerability assessment it removed the “Server-level firewall rules should be tracked and maintained at a strict minimum” which is high risk. However when I add the firewall setting from database view (not from the server view) and ran the vulnerability assessment scan above risk showing again. How it possible even server firewalls also not showing the record. 
I am bit confused how this happening.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you are clicking on the button "Set server firewall" from within the database blade in the Azure portal. Correct? If so, this will indeed set the server firewall rules, and so it will be flagged by VA2065. Database level firewall rules are not accessible through the Azure portal. You can read more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-firewall-configure).

Please note that the fact that VA2065 fails does not necessarily mean that you should close off the server level firewall entirely. Instead, you should evaluate the results (click on the failing check) and make sure that the rules in the firewall are correct. If they are - set that as your baseline. Now scan the database again and VA2065 will "pass per baseline". Only subsequent changes to the server's firewall rules (that do not match the set baseline) will result in a failure.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue. The reason you get this **"Vulnerability Assessment"** is because **"Advanced data security"** is **ON** on your sql server. The Assessment is quite strict and has a cost to it as well. The purpose of this assement if to make you think about security issue even "basic stuff" like should all azure instances be allowed to connect to your database?

That is what the "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps" is all about and would you as an database azure admin allowed for other instances in Azure to connect to this SQL Server and Database?

VA2065 - Server-level firewall rules should be tracked and maintained at a strict minimum

- Firewall Rule Name: AllowAllWindowsAzureIps
- Start Address: 0.0.0.0
- End Address: 0.0.0.0

If the answer is yes... and **yes** is the most logical choice then the way to **solve this** is to allow "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps" for the given server by pressing the button **"Approve as Baseline"** which will tell the server that it is okay to have "AllowAllWindowsAzureIps" going forward.